# Tint a Texture2D in the same way Unity does

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, sprite, texture2d, tint

I'm trying to tint a Texture2D with a Color in Unity3D in same same way the sprite renderer does.
What is the best way to do this?

Edit:
This are the codes i tried:

```cs
  private Color Tint(Color source, Color tint) {
    Color tinted = source;
    //tinted.r = Math.Min(Math.Max(0f, (source.r + (255f - source.r) * tint.r)), 255f);
    //tinted.g = Math.Min(Math.Max(0f, (source.g + (255f - source.g) * tint.g)), 255f);
    //tinted.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(0f, (source.b + (255f - source.b) * tint.b)), 255f);

    //tinted.r = (float)Math.Floor(source.r * tint.r / 255f);
    //tinted.g = (float)Math.Floor(source.g * tint.g / 255f);
    //tinted.b = (float)Math.Floor(source.b * tint.b / 255f);

    Color.RGBToHSV(source, out float sourceH, out float sourceS, out float sourceV);
    Color.RGBToHSV(tint, out float tintH, out float tintS, out float tintV);
    tinted = Color.HSVToRGB(tintH, tintS, sourceV);
    tinted.a = source.a;
    return tinted;
  }
```

Comment: Sir, can you please let us know how did you tried this on your own. Any code that you may have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik the tint for `Renderer` in general is done by multiplication (black stays black) and could simply be achieved using the [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-operator_multiply.html)

```c#
private Color Tint(Color source, Color tint) 
{
    return source * tint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much flexible way is to use lerp

```
Color original = Color.red;
Color tint = Color.cyan;
float tintPercentage = 0.3f;

// This will give you original color tinted by tintPercentage
UnityEngine.Color.Lerp(original, tint, tintPercentage);

// this will give you original color
UnityEngine.Color.Lerp(original, tint, 0f);

// this will give you full tint color
UnityEngine.Color.Lerp(original, tint, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late to the party here, but for anyone looking for a simple way to do this in 2023 (or later)... here's a function that will return a newly tinted texture:

```
public Texture2D TintTexture(Texture2D texture2D, Color tint)
{
    // cache variables
    int width = texture2D.width;
    int height = texture2D.height;
    Color[] pixels = new Color[width * height];
    int pixelIndex = 0;

    // iterate through each pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            pixels[pixelIndex] = texture2D.GetPixel(j, i) * tint;
            pixelIndex++;
        }
    }

    // build a new texture from the pixels
    Texture2D result = new Texture2D(width, height);
    result.SetPixels(pixels);
    result.Apply();
    
    return result;
}
```